# How to send multipart/form-data request in body in Python without a file

Tags: python, rest, api

**Its Not duplicate of other question** I would like to know who the body data can be sent as multi form data. In other question its mentions as how to upload file. I really dont have any file to upload or may be I dont know how to do it. Please help

I have to send a Post request in which the body is multipart/form-data

```
import requests    
url = 'https://myapp-local/api/address'
    headers = {'Accept':'application/json','Content-Type':'multipart/form-data','token': token, 'referer':'https://myapp-local/api/address'}
```

now in body I need to send few values like

```
address_name=Ram, current_time=1557249595, house_no=303, district=theni, address_type=permemnant
```

These values I need to send as form data. How can I do that? Please Help

Comment: Are you sure you need multi-part - that would normally be used where there is a lot of data e.g. for file upload.

Comment: Yes, What I posted is actually a very less data. I have a lot of data in Body @barny